# Jacoco JmockIt error with Gradle build -java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: gradle, jacoco, jmockit

I am using jacoco gradle plugin. My Unit test cases are failing and getting below exception. I searched in form but didnt get answer. Same test cases are working fine with maven (jacoco-maven) plugin.

ava.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)

I am using jmockit 1.12 and jacoco toolVersion = '0.7.1.201405082137'

Comment: What version of JMockit library are you using during Gradle build/test? If it's not compatible with the jacoco version then it cries with the above message.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the root cause is that I **didn't** put jmockit dependency **before** junit dependency. So please ensure you have dependencies like the following:

```
testCompile 'org.jmockit:jmockit:1.29'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Jmockit and Jacoco instruments the class files. Jmockit does it first during the build process and when jacoco tries the same (later in the process) it says "oh oh, can't instrument an already instrumented class file". This issue happened with older versions of jacoco and jmockit. To see this error, enable `--stacktrace` option during Gradle build or `--debug`.

Now, using the latest jacoco and jmockit versions, we can solve this issue easily.

If you use jacoco (or use [the latest one here](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3Aorg.jacoco)):

```
toolVersion="0.7.1.201405082137"
```

or

```
toolVersion="0.7.2.201409121644"
```

or

```
toolVersion="0.7.5.201505241946"
```

See this: [changes that went in 0.7.1 version](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html).

For JMockit, you have to use jmockit version: 1.8 at least or later (1.9 to 1.13).

```
org.jmockit:jmockit:1.8
```

See this: changes that went under 1.8 version: http://jmockit.github.io/changes.html

I see the latest jmockit version out there is now 1.19, so use these two in Gradle with versions which are compatible and support each other.